# pass props through template

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

Is it possible to pass custom config attributes through a template like this?:

```
<template v-slot:name="{data}" config="myConfig">{{data.field}}</template>
```

If possible how do I get access to that in the render method?

```
let a = this.$scopedSlots.name[0]['config'];  //something like this
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you pass custom config through `props`. You can access it in the render method with `this.$props`.

Take a look at the [doc](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html) to see how to pass data to child component.

Comment: Yea, I knew I could pass a comprehensive data structure through props of the component but I wanted individual slot data related with each slot template to be passed in through it for readability purposes. From your answer I take it that this is not possible.